# Align itemize bullet within tikz environment

Tags: tikz-pgf

When putting a `tikzpicture` environment inside an `itemize` environment, the bullet point is not correctly aligned with the `tikz` picture. In this case, "correct" means that the bullet should be vertically centered with respect to the picture.

I've previously just tweaked the `baseline` manually to get what I want, but the tweak will depend on the font I'm using, etc. I'd like to avoid the use of a [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Unnamed_numerical_constants) in my baseline tweak, so that it will adjust automatically to the font I'm using. Any suggestions how to accomplish that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item
        \begin{tikzpicture}%[baseline = -2.5pt] % magic number tweak
            \draw [very thick, ->] (0,0) -- (2,0);
            \node[left] at (0,0) {XX};
            \node[right] at (2,0) {YY};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No magic number: `-0.5ex` will work in the majority of the cases.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Not in the document I'm writing now. With ``-0.5ex``, the bullet aligns with the upper half of a x-height character rather than being centered with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are better off aligning to a known natural point in a node:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A.base)] % magic number tweak
    \draw [very thick, ->] (0,0) -- (2,0);
    \node[left] at (0,0) (A) {XX};
    \node[right] at (2,0) {YY};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\item \( X \)
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

If you want to fix the horizontal alignment (which you didn't ask about but Barbara Beeton did) then you will have to work a little harder.

[image: Sample with horizontal spacing]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item
  \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(A.base)] % magic number tweak
    \node at (0,0) (A) {XX};
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgf/inner xsep}{\myAxsep}
    \node at (2,0) (B) {YY};
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{/pgf/inner xsep}{\myBxsep}
    \draw [very thick, ->] (A) -- (B);
    \pgfresetboundingbox
    \useasboundingbox ($(A.south west)+(\myAxsep,0)$) rectangle
    ($(B.north east)-(\myBxsep,0)$);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  and some text.
\item \( X \)
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

I have perhaps been over cautious checking the value of the x-separation after each box, but this may well be necessary in more complicated code.

Comment: vertical alignment is good, but what's the extra space between the bullet and the expression in the first `\item`?

Comment: @barbarabeeton The poster didn't ask about that, but I have added extra sample code to deal with that issue.