# Align itemize bullet within tikz environment, v2

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is a direct follow-up to my question [Align itemize bullet within tikz environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203877/align-itemize-bullet-within-tikz-environment). I basically have the same question as then, except that this time, I need to align the `itemize` bullet with an arrow that is drawn between an `above` and a `below` `node`.

By default, the alignment shows up like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline = default]
            \draw [very thick, ->] (0,0) -- (2,0);
            \node[above] at (1,0) {Text above};
            \node[below] at (1,0) {Text below};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Following [Andrew Swann](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/15925/andrew-swann)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203881/9077), I tried to name my drawing (e.g. `(myarrow)`) and set the baseline to its base, but this doesn't work - I can presumably only name nodes. So I create an empty node that I name:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline = (A.base)]
            \draw [very thick, ->] (0,0) -- (2,0);
            \node at (0,0) (A) {};
            \node[above] at (1,0) {Text above};
            \node[below] at (1,0) {Text below};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But the bullet is still vertically misaligned with the arrow. What do I need to do in order to set the baseline of the `tikzpicture` environment to the base of the arrow?

---

**EDIT**

It was suggested in a comment to [Align itemize bullet within tikz environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203877/align-itemize-bullet-within-tikz-environment) to use `-.5ex` as the baseline, and Kevin C's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/224128/9077) here suggests the same approach. While this is a good approximation to a perfect vertical alignment, it doesn't quite get there. As indicated already in my comment to [Align itemize bullet within tikz environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203877/align-itemize-bullet-within-tikz-environment), how good the approximation is will depend on the font used (and this means that one would need to manually tweak the exact baseline on a document per document basis), and in this case, one can also see that the alignment is slightly off. Cf. the MWE below (I've added the red midline manually later).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline = -.5ex]
            \draw [very thick, ->] (0,0) -- (2,0);
            \node[above] at (1,0) {Text above};
            \node[below] at (1,0) {Text below};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that item bullets are usually `.5ex` above the baseline. So if you want your arrow to align exactly as the bullet, just shift everything up vertically by this distance.

Specifically, you can use node `(A)`'s base as your arrow's starting point, and add `.5ex` to the above and below nodes.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item %
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline = (A.base)]
            \node[inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) (A) {};
            \draw [very thick, ->] ([yshift=.5ex]A.base) -- +(2,0);
            \node[above] at (1,.5ex) {Text above};
            \node[below] at (1,.5ex) {Text below};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{itemize}    
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: This is a good approximation, but it doesn't quite get there. See the edit to my question. Also, I think it would be an easier approach to just add ``[baseline = -.5ex]`` to begin with (see my new MWE).