# Aligning bullet in tikz with some other issues

Tags: automation, tikz-pic

I want to change a few things in the following picture:
[image]
**(1) Aligning the bullet `(d)` vertically upwards from where the picture starts.

(2) Changing direction of the arrow at `q4` from right to left (in this picture, the direction is from left to right)

(3) The stretched self loops at `q3` and `q4` like at `q2`.**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
\tikzset{every state/.style}
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item
    \item
    \item
    \item
      \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.8cm,semithick]
    \node[initial,state] (q0)                    {$q_0$};
    \node[state]         (q1) [above right of=q0]      {$q_1$};
    \node[state,accepting]         (q2) [right of=q1]      {$q_2$};
    \node[state]         (q3) [below right of=q0] {$q_3$};
    \node[state]         (q4) [above right of=q3] {$q_4$};
    \node[state,accepting]         (q5) [right of=q3,xshift=1cm] {$q_5$};
    
    \path (q0) edge    node {0} (q1)
               edge    node[left,xshift=-0.2cm] {1} (q3)
          (q1) edge    node {1} (q2)
               edge    node[right,xshift=0.1cm] {0} (q4)
          (q2) edge [loop]        node[above] {0,1} (q2)
          (q3) edge [loop below]        node[below] {1} (q3)
               edge    node[right,xshift=0.1cm] {0} (q4)
          (q4) edge [loop right]        node {0} (q4)
               edge [bend left]        node[below] {1} (q5)
          (q5) edge [bend left]        node[above] {0} (q4)
               edge    node {1} (q3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I tried [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224113/align-itemize-bullet-within-tikz-environment-v2) to align bullets but this did not work out for me.

Comment: Please make your code compilable. From your  use of `\begin{enumerate}[(a)]`, I guess, you use the `enumerate` package in your actual document. This package is missing in your MWE causing the document to not compile properly.

Comment: @leandriis i have edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,automata,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item
    \item
    \item
    \item
      \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-0.6\baselineskip] current bounding box.north)},
    auto,
    node distance=12mm and 12mm,
    every edge/.style = {draw, semithick, -Stealth, shorten >=1pt},
    every edge quotes/.style = {font=\small, inner sep=2pt},
    every loop/.style = {looseness=12} 
                        ]
    \node (q0) [state, initial]     {$q_0$};
    \begin{scope}[nodes=state]
    \node (q1) [above right=of q0]  {$q_1$};
    \node (q2) [state, accepting, 
                right=of q1]        {$q_2$};
    \node (q3) [below right=of q0]  {$q_3$};
    \node (q4) [above right=of q3] {$q_4$};
    \node (q5) [accepting,
                right=of q3]        {$q_5$};
    \end{scope}
    \path (q0) edge ["0" ']             (q1)
               edge ["1"]               (q3)
          (q1) edge ["1"]               (q2)
               edge ["0" ']             (q4)
          (q2) edge [loop above, 
                     "{0,1}"]           (q2)
          (q3) edge [loop below, "1"]   ()   
          (q4) edge ["0" ']             (q3)
          (q4) edge [loop right, "0"]   ()
               edge [bend left,  "1"]   (q5)
          (q5) edge [bend left,  "0"]   (q4)
               edge ["1"]               (q3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

- used are `positioning` and `quotes` package
- syntax of positioning is in this case `right=of q0` etc (observe interchange of `=` and `of` in comparison in your MWE)
- defined are styles for edges and edges quotes and loops

**Edit:**
or by use `node distance=24mm and 24mm, on grid,` in above MWE, the diagram is:

[image]

**Edit:** According to OP comment, image should be aligned with word *start* in diagram. This can be obtained by

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-0.5ex] q0.base)},
```

With id the result of above MWE is:

[image]

Comment: perfect for me. just two things I want to know. what is `current bounding box.north` and how to put value for `looseness`?

Comment: @ManjoyDas, `current bounding box` is invisible box around  image. Anchor `north means, that image baseline is at north (top) of box, however as I understood you, you like to have aligned item and top simbol in image, so I shift  image up for `0.6 \baselineskip`. Size of the `looseness` is determined in `every loop/.style = {looseness=<value>}` in `tikzpicture` options. Its default value is 8, In MWE in answer it is increased to 12.  if you like to have even bigger loop, just increase number. More details  you can find in section *74.3 Curves*,  page 841, Ti*k*Z & PGF manual, version 3.1.8b.

Comment: actually I wanted to align item and `start` at same level.

Comment: @ManjoyDas, that is not clear from your question. You only need to change `baseline to: `baseline={([yshift=-0.5ex] q0.base)},`. See addendum to answer (hopefully  now answer deserve to be upvoted  too :-) )